# Exact definition of "vehemently"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, adverbs

My work mates and I are arguing about this term since none of us can comprehend its exact definition. Can I use the expression "I have been struggling vehemently to get this email sent since last month!" with validity?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Comment: It would help if you presented the rival definitions that each of you has championed.  Without that detail and corresponding detail in response, your friends are unlikely to be happy with any answer you take back to them.

Answer (score 4):

The core meaning of *vehement* is ‘intense, severe’, so, yes, you can use the adverb *vehemently* to describe the way in which you have been struggling. However, its use is mostly restricted to describing speech, so don’t be surprised if people question its use in other contexts.

Comment: thank you for your timely response! yes checked the dict, but needed a more thorough explanation

Comment: I like [thefreedictionary's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vehemently) definition; ***vehemently** - characterized by forcefulness of expression or intensity of emotion or conviction*. That strongly implies it's more applicable to speech/expression, rather than *actions* such as "struggling".

Answer (score 0):

*Struggle* is a verb, *vehemently* is an adverb, so they may go together cohesively.

Comment: Like _sleep_ and _furiously_?

Comment: That's syntax. The question is about semantics. Not every adverb goes together with every verb.